Node setup geo/material for randomizing visibility in a grid
Does anyone know a way to use i.e the Musgrave texture to randomize visibility of an item arrayed into a grid?
I've tried applying the array, and then separating by loose parts and adding the Object Info Random node into the Vector of the Musgrave Texture, which I plugged into the Alpha. This unfortunately does not work as there are still shadows visible from the items that are "hidden".
I'm certain there's a geo node setup for this, but I haven't been able to find it.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!


Would you mind telling us which Blender version you use and show us (at least) the settings in the Material Properties tab (Blend Mode, Shadow Mode etc.) or even upload the file here https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question? But most likely I would assume you have left the Shadow Mode at the default Opaque. Try switching it to Alpha Clip or Alpha Hashed instead.

Yeah, I would lean toward using a GN setup with a grid mesh, Mesh to Points, Instance on points, then just use the musgrave texture to control the selection of the IOP node. Rather than messing with materials.
